# Sending WM messages from a child control to its parent form

Tags: c#, winforms, wndproc

I have a **borderless** `Form`, with a `Panel` docked on top (as if it was the title bar). so far everything is ok except for one problem that I can't figure out on my own.

I have to following code in the `MouseDown` event of the `Panel` to be able to move the `Form`:

```
SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);
```

Of course after importing the external API:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
```

I also have overridden the `WndProc` method for the `Form` to be able to resize the `Form` as any other regular form in Windows (taken from a SO post, can't find the link now):

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (!_resizable)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        return;
    }

    const UInt32 WM_NCHITTEST = 0x0084;
    const UInt32 WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200;

    const UInt32 HTLEFT = 10;
    const UInt32 HTRIGHT = 11;
    const UInt32 HTBOTTOMRIGHT = 17;
    const UInt32 HTBOTTOM = 15;
    const UInt32 HTBOTTOMLEFT = 16;
    const UInt32 HTTOP = 12;
    const UInt32 HTTOPLEFT = 13;
    const UInt32 HTTOPRIGHT = 14;

    const int RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE = 10;
    bool handled = false;
    if (m.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST || m.Msg == WM_MOUSEMOVE)
    {
        Size formSize = this.Size;
        Point screenPoint = new Point(m.LParam.ToInt32());
        Point clientPoint = this.PointToClient(screenPoint);

        Dictionary<UInt32, Rectangle> boxes = new Dictionary<UInt32, Rectangle>()
{
    {HTBOTTOMLEFT, new Rectangle(0, formSize.Height - RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE, RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE, RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE)},
    {HTBOTTOM, new Rectangle(RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE, formSize.Height - RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE, formSize.Width - 2*RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE, RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE)},
    {HTBOTTOMRIGHT, new Rectangle(formSize.Width - RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE, formSize.Height - RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE, RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE, RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE)},
    {HTRIGHT, new Rectangle(formSize.Width - RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE, RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE, RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE, formSize.Height - 2*RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE)},
    {HTTOPRIGHT, new Rectangle(formSize.Width - RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE, 0, RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE, RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE) },
    {HTTOP, new Rectangle(RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE, 0, formSize.Width - 2*RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE, RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE) },
    {HTTOPLEFT, new Rectangle(0, 0, RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE, RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE) },
    {HTLEFT, new Rectangle(0, RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE, RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE, formSize.Height - 2*RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE) }
};

        foreach (KeyValuePair<UInt32, Rectangle> hitBox in boxes)
        {
            if (this.WindowState != FormWindowState.Maximized
                && hitBox.Value.Contains(clientPoint))
            {
                m.Result = (IntPtr)hitBox.Key;
                handled = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (!handled)
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    else
        this.Refresh();
}
```

Now the above code works just fine, the only problem is the upper border, since the upper part of the `Form` is covered by the `Panel`. So I thought I can do something like this in the pane's `MouseDown` and `MouseMove` events to make windows think the events are coming from the form.

In the `MouseDown` event:

```
const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
(sender as Control).Capture = false;
Int32 lparam = MakeLParam(e.X, e.Y);
Message msg = Message.Create(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)lparam);
WndProc(ref msg);
```

And in the `MouseMove` event:

```
const int WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200;
(sender as Control).Capture = false;
Int32 lparam = MakeLParam(e.X, e.Y);
Message msg = Message.Create(Handle, WM_MOUSEMOVE, IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)lparam);
WndProc(ref msg);
```

and this is the `MakeLParam` method:

```
private int MakeLParam(int LoWord, int HiWord)
{
    return ((HiWord << 16) | (LoWord & 0xffff));
}
```

Anyway, it just does not work.

**How can I make windows believe that the mouse movement/clicks are coming from the form itself rather than from the panel?**

Comment: Are you really sending 0 for lParam in your first code sample? Also, try PostMessage instead

Comment: @PeterRitchie yes, I am sending 0, but that part is working fine, the problem is in the last two snippets..

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in a [different forum](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?568015-Move-and-Resize-a-Control-or-a-Borderless-Form-using-window-messages-(smooth!)). It's easy. Basically, you will handle the `MouseMove` event and then send the resize message manually instead of passing all the child controls messages. The secret is in sending a `WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN` message along with the direction.

Here is a sample code (in VB.NET, but I'll assume it's easy for all C# coders to understand it):

```
Private Sub Form1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseMove
    'Calculate which direction to resize based on mouse position

    If e.Location.X < BorderWidth And e.Location.Y < BorderWidth Then
        resizeDir = ResizeDirection.TopLeft

    ElseIf e.Location.X < BorderWidth And e.Location.Y > Me.Height - BorderWidth Then
        resizeDir = ResizeDirection.BottomLeft

    ElseIf e.Location.X > Me.Width - BorderWidth And e.Location.Y > Me.Height - BorderWidth Then
        resizeDir = ResizeDirection.BottomRight

    ElseIf e.Location.X > Me.Width - BorderWidth And e.Location.Y < BorderWidth Then
        resizeDir = ResizeDirection.TopRight

    ElseIf e.Location.X < BorderWidth Then
        resizeDir = ResizeDirection.Left

    ElseIf e.Location.X > Me.Width - BorderWidth Then
        resizeDir = ResizeDirection.Right

    ElseIf e.Location.Y < BorderWidth Then
        resizeDir = ResizeDirection.Top

    ElseIf e.Location.Y > Me.Height - BorderWidth Then
        resizeDir = ResizeDirection.Bottom

    Else
        resizeDir = ResizeDirection.None
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseDown
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left And Me.WindowState <> FormWindowState.Maximized Then
        ResizeForm(resizeDir)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ResizeForm(ByVal direction As ResizeDirection)
    Dim dir As Integer = -1
    Select Case direction
        Case ResizeDirection.Left
            dir = HTLEFT
        Case ResizeDirection.TopLeft
            dir = HTTOPLEFT
        Case ResizeDirection.Top
            dir = HTTOP
        Case ResizeDirection.TopRight
            dir = HTTOPRIGHT
        Case ResizeDirection.Right
            dir = HTRIGHT
        Case ResizeDirection.BottomRight
            dir = HTBOTTOMRIGHT
        Case ResizeDirection.Bottom
            dir = HTBOTTOM
        Case ResizeDirection.BottomLeft
            dir = HTBOTTOMLEFT
    End Select

    If dir <> -1 Then
        ReleaseCapture()
        SendMessage(Me.Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, dir, 0)
    End If
End Sub
```